# Minimization of residual in Shi-Tomasi feature extraction

Tags: derivatives, partial-differential-equations, optimization, computer-vision

I don't understand how in the following paper [https://users.cs.duke.edu/~tomasi/papers/shi/TR_93-1399_Cornell.pdf](https://users.cs.duke.edu/%7Etomasi/papers/shi/TR_93-1399_Cornell.pdf) (Good features to track) the residual (Eq. 3.1) is differentiated so that Equations 3.2 and 3.3 are obtained. Can someone explain this to me?

$\epsilon = \int\int_W [J(A$***x***$)+ d]^2 \omega$(***x***)$d$***x*** (3.1)

$\partial\epsilon/\partial D = 2\int\int_W [J(A$***x***$)+ d] (\partial J/\partial x, \partial J/\partial y)^T$ ***x***$^T\omega$(***x***)$d$***x*** (3.2)

$\partial\epsilon/\partial d = 2\int\int_W [J(A$***x***$)+ d] (\partial J/\partial x, \partial J/\partial y)\omega$(***x***)$d$***x*** (3.3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the (scalar) integrand
$\phi = \left[ J(\mathbf{u})-I(\mathbf{x}) \right]^2$
where $\mathbf{u}=\mathbf{Ax+d}$.

The derivative wrt vector $\mathbf{d}$ is easily computed
\begin{eqnarray}
d\phi
&=& 2 \left[ J(\mathbf{u})-I(\mathbf{x}) \right] 
\left( \frac{\partial J}{\partial \mathbf{u}}:d\mathbf{u} \right) \tag{*}\\
&=& 2 \left[ J(\mathbf{u})-I(\mathbf{x}) \right] 
\left( \frac{\partial J}{\partial \mathbf{u}}:d\mathbf{d} \right)
\end{eqnarray}
so the integrand derivative reads
$$
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial \mathbf{d}}
=
2 \left[ J(\mathbf{u})-I(\mathbf{x}) \right] 
\nabla J(\mathbf{u})
$$

Looking at the paper $\mathbf{A}=\mathbf{D+I}$
\begin{eqnarray}
d\phi
&=& (*) = 2 \left[ J(\mathbf{u})-I(\mathbf{x}) \right] 
\left( \frac{\partial J}{\partial \mathbf{u}}:(d\mathbf{A})\mathbf{x} \right) \\
&=& 2 \left[ J(\mathbf{u})-I(\mathbf{x}) \right] 
\left( \frac{\partial J}{\partial \mathbf{u}} \mathbf{x}^T:d\mathbf{D} \right)
\end{eqnarray}
so the integrand derivative reads
$$
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial \mathbf{D}}
=
2 \left[ J(\mathbf{u})-I(\mathbf{x}) \right] 
\nabla J(\mathbf{u})\mathbf{x}^T
$$

Note that the gradient of $J$ should be evaluated at $\mathbf{u}$.